# Getting gems added to bundle install from the local gem repository

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundle

I am trying to understand how bundle install resolves dependencies for a ruby project. I have all the required gems in the path where `bundle install` would download its gems to, but only when  I run `bundle install` do those gems become available to my ruby code. For example, `mongrel` is available under the gem path but the line `require 'mongrel'` only finds it after I run `bundle install`. Otherwise it throws an error saying the file is not found.

Since I already have all the gems in the gem repo, would there be a way to get the project to know about those files and resolve them without having to issue a `bundle install`?

Answer (score 1):

no. bundler uses the `Gemfile.lock` to resolve the dependencies. if you did not run `bundle install` the `Gemfile.lock` would not be updated.

if you want to use your locally installed gems, you can run `bundle install --local`

Comment: thanks phoet. Then my question is if it would be possible to modify `Gemfile.lock` in such a way that it resolve the dependencies? The `.lock` file does seem to be a text file, so why couldn't I just modify it to resolve the dependencies?

Comment: another thing that you can do, that will not be portable though, is to set a `:path` for the gem if it's installed locally.